# How to set style on button action

Tags: rebol, rebol2

*Note*: This was a question on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34867301#34867301)

How do I change the style of the button on press?

```
l: layout [

style bteal button teal
style bred button red

b1: bteal "Ok" [b1/style: 'bred]
]

view l
```

Want to change like this on `button` click:

[image: initially] -> [image: expected on click]

The answer has probably something to do with vid being a dialect.
Also, how the `style` word evaluates it's content

#### Addendum

Probably not.

Before:

```
>> ? b1/style
B1/STYLE is a word of value: bteal
```

After:

```
>> ? b1/style
B1/STYLE is a word of value: bred
```

So, what is being set is correct. Perhaps an event needs to be triggered?

Answer (score 4):

`style` has a meaning in `layout` function only, `layout` function uses it as a shortcut to generate new faces with predefined facets (color, size etc.)

So, changing a face's style doesn't change anything. You need to change the facets (properties of the face) directly.

```
lay: layout [
    style by box yellow
    b: by "Test" [b/color: random white  show b]
]
view lay
```

But if you do the same on a `button` you may confused because its color wouldn't be changed:

```
lay: layout [
    b: button yellow "Test" [b/color: random white  show b]
]
view lay
```

It is because buttons have some effects in `effects` facet and the color is defined there during the generation of face inside layout function.

```
>> ? b/effects
B/EFFECTS is a block of value: [
    [gradient 0x1 255.255.32 223.223.0]
    [gradient 0x-1 255.255.32 223.223.0]
]
```

if you `clear` that block then you can see the change or you should change that block accordingly.

Edit:

Here is a working version of your example:

```
l: layout [
    style bteal button teal effect []
    style bred button red effect []
    b1: bteal "Ok" [b1/color: red]
]
view l
```

Comment: According to http://www.pat665.free.fr/gtk/rebol-view.html#sect6

that code worked as of June 2004.

Perhaps style worked different circa that time?

Comment: I don't know if it was really changing the look of button or just change the value of `style` word. Thanks for the reference.